# Does JVM memory management work the same on Windows and Linux?

Tags: windows, linux, memory, jvm, visualvm

My original question is that, is this technically rational to check the required **heap-size** of my Java program on Windows 7, via **VisualVM**, and come to this conclusion that the program will require the same amount of heap on Linux(RedHat) as well?

I don't know how the system(OS or even CPU and RAM), affect memory management of JVM.
well, the windows is my development system with 4GB of RAM and a Core 2 Due CPU, however the
Linux is the production system with 32GB of RAM and multiple powerfull processors,

Actually, my concern is that the program on Linux might need more memory. less is ok.

Comment: It probably will behave slightly differently on your Linux server. You might tune your JVM. However, you could trust its default behavior at first. Why using more RAM is an issue, when more RAM is available???

Comment: Actually there are many other programs running on the server as well, so not much RAM is available.

Comment: Ask or interact with the sysadmin of the production server. You may want to tune the JVM (thru appropriate program arguments) when starting it.

Comment: In fact, I want to tune it, my question is that can I draw tune parameters out of my windows? where I tested it, and it worked fine.

Comment: Probably not, because your server has a different architecture.

Comment: Actually I think since the program itself decides when to claim memory and when to release it, I guess about this issue (required heap size) it will perform the same on both environments, I just need to make sure. thank you anyway @Basile.